# Try to read text , put on list , then compare on list and finally replace txt file

Tags: vb.net

Trying to read a .txt file , put items to list, then on textbox change compare if the string exists in the list. Finally write the new list on the same .txt file.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim stockList As New List(Of String)
private sub
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\path\file.txt"))
end sub
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
TextBox1.ReadOnlyChanged

    Dim text As String = TextBox1.Text
    If TextBox1.Text <> "TRAINING" Then
        For Each item As Object In ListBox1.Items
            If item.ToString = text Then
                MsgBox("This code has already been used.", 0, "cheat attempt violation") ' Else alert the user that item already exist
            Else
                ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)

            End If
        Next
    End If
    IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Users\path\file.txt", ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a UI control to store data, you should store the data in a variable. I'm not sure if you really need to show the data in a ListBox, so in the following example code I didn't.

If you use a List(Of String) instead of an array of strings, it is simpler to add another item before saving it.

The [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains) method I used in the example can take a second parameter which does the comparison of the item - I guessed that you might want to ignore the case (e.g. "ABC" is the same as "aBc") so I used `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`.

I suspect that you want to use the [Control.Validating Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating) instead of the TextChanged event. When the data has been validated, the [Control.Validated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validated) event handler is used to save it.

I put one TextBox and one Button on the form, so that the focus could change away from the TextBox, e.g. when pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>, to fire the validating event.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim dataFile As String = "C:\temp\grains.txt"
    Dim alreadyUsed As List(Of String) = Nothing

    Sub LoadAlreadyUsed(filename As String)
        'TODO: Add exception checking, e.g., the file might not exist.
        alreadyUsed = File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList()

    End Sub

    Sub SaveAlreadyUsed(filename As String)
        File.WriteAllLines(dataFile, alreadyUsed)

    End Sub

    Function CodeIsAlreadyUsed(newCode As String) As Boolean
        Return alreadyUsed.Contains(newCode, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    End Function

    Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
        ' Do nothing if the user has clicked the form close button
        ' See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920770/closing-the-c-sharp-windows-form-by-avoiding-textbox-validation
        If Me.ActiveControl.Equals(sender) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim txt = DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text

        If CodeIsAlreadyUsed(txt) Then
            MessageBox.Show("This code has already been used.", "Cheat attempt violation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            e.Cancel = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validated
        ' The Validated event is raised before the FormClosing event.
        ' We do not want to save the data when the form is closing.
        If Me.ActiveControl.Equals(sender) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim txt = DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text
        alreadyUsed.Add(txt)
        SaveAlreadyUsed(dataFile)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadAlreadyUsed(dataFile)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: @GiannisStefanidis I have updated the code to put the saving into the Validated event handler, which is where it should be.