# Close button not working in windows forms application

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

i am validating my text box through the validating and validated events , below is my code

```
    private void tbms_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbms.Text.Length==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ms is Empty");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    private void tbms_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Error");
    }
```

Its works nice , but the problem i am facing is if there is no text in text box and i want to close the application through the cancel button on control box its show me the message box that Ms is Empty and prompt me again to the window . when i put some text in text box and i click the cancel button the application closed. Kindly give hint how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882523/how-to-skip-validating-after-clicking-on-a-forms-cancel-button

Comment: @RJ Lohan , i can do it using an extra button by naming it cancel button and setting the cause validation to false, or auto validate to disable etc etc , but i do not want to use a extra button to close the app, i only want to use the cancel button on the control box. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation will also occur when your form is being closed.  If your Validating event sets the e.Cancel property to true then the default FormClosing event will stop the form from closing.  You can work around this like this:

```
private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.Disable;
    this.Close();    // or this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
}
```

Comment: So you mean i have to use an extra button to close the application , and have to hide the control box.

Comment: You can also implement the FormClosing event handler and force the e.Cancel property back to false.

Comment: Thank you very much sir , this is what i was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set property `KeyPreview` to `True` in your Form.
2. Add a button and write the ESC code (Ex. `Me.Dispose()`)
3. In your Form, select your button from the "CancelButton Property List".
4. The button always must be `Visible = True` to work. If you don't want to show it, put the button behind any other object or localize it at `top = -100`  and `left = -1`, for example. But the button always must be `Visible = true`

Comment: This is/was the problem:  button always must be Visible = true

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the "CausesValidation" property to false on the cancel button