# C# form validation with tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox, tooltip

I am coding a C# Forms application and I have a question about validating a form.

I have a `textbox` called `textBoxCodeToSearchFor` that I want to validate when I press a button. If the `textbox` does not have any text in it, I need a `tooltip` to be shown.

Here is my code:

```
private void textBoxCodeToSearchFor_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxCodeToSearchFor.Text))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        toolTip.Show("Please enter the code to search for", textBoxCodeToSearchFor);
    }
}
```

On the button click I have the following code:

```
bool validated = this.Validate();
```

The `tooltip` is then shown, however, I cannot close the form when pressing a cancel button.

How can I shown a `tooltip` for a `textbox` if the `textbox` does not validate, but still close out of the form is wanted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried creating an onclosing event and seeing if its reached when you press the close button? it may be practical for you to dispose of the tooltip prior to the form closing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinForm UI Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769184/winform-ui-validation)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to skip Validating after clicking on a Form's Cancel button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882523/how-to-skip-validating-after-clicking-on-a-forms-cancel-button)